# Text to Column has now changed my Excel's pasting preferences permanently

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql

I recently used the text to columns functionality in excel.  It was used to split out one singular column that was delimited by commas.  After I successfully made the adjustment, my excel now will not paste SQL output correctly into any excel workbook I open.  Even if it's a brand new workbook.  All I can find around this are instructions to fixing one sheet of data, but how do I revert my Excel back to the default settings to allow for pasting again?

Comment: Perform a text-to-columns operation without the comma as the separator. Do it on any data once and it should reset it to whatever settings you used.

Comment: Can you provide samples of the CSV data as well as the SQL data? Also how is the SQL data supposed to look vs how it looks now? I highly doubt this is the cause of your problems. More likely your computer's regional and language settings have been changed. Note, when importing either a CSV file or splitting data with text to columns, Excel uses the local computer's regional and language settings, including comma separators/delimiters etc. Also note, the windows language bar shortcut left shift+alt can sometimes change these localisations settings by accident.